# Find all match in firebase real time database

Tags: android, search, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello please I need search in database in firebase all  appearance with  one parameter and write it on display or save in object. (if save in object I can process it)

My database looking

[image: My data]

And i need get all match  mDatabaseReference.child("horse").child(kon.getUid()).child("plemeno") with "Hnedy"

and save somewhere. or process write on display and search second.

I don't know why...

Thanks.

If I need run over all database for search or it's simply here.

Please give me all advice I select best for me.

If you need more info please write, but I don't know how you need.

..I would not know what to say

////////////////////////////////////////////////

for first I write on display all databse with thise code..

```
private void addEventFirebaseListener() {
    //Progressing
    circular_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    list_data.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mDatabaseReference.child("horse").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(list_kone.size() > 0)
                list_kone.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Kon kon = postSnapshot.getValue(Kon.class);
                list_kone.add(kon);
            }
            ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(All.this,list_kone);
            list_data.setAdapter(adapter);

            circular_progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            list_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

but I thing so it's no important for search

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("horse").orderByChild("plemeno").equalTo("Hnedy").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
            // retrieve the data into an object: kon here
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Kon kon = postSnapshot.getValue(Kon.class);
                if (cenaFilter && kon.getCena().equals("100")) {
                   // RETRIEVE DATA
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Here `cenaFilter` is a boolean which equals to `true` if the user has selected this specific filter, `false` otherwise

Comment: and from which variable get all other infrmation? for printout. dataSnapshot?

Comment: As you usually do: `for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                ...
            }`

Comment: Thanks it's work... But If i want search for more critery for example plemeno : hnedy 
and  cena: 100?

Comment: Ok, then you can accept the answer please :) far as I know, with firebase you can't order/filter the data two times. You could do it inside the for loop, like this: `for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){ if (yourObj.getCena().equals("100")) {...} }`

Comment: please update your answre or edit for search by 2 critery

Comment: With firebase database queries you can order/filter only one value at time. If you want to filter by two values, the simpler thing to do is to retrieve all data (filtering only by one value) and filter the second value locally

Comment: and how can practise it? locally

Comment: You can do it, for example, inside you `for` loop into the `ValueEventListener`

Comment: if (cenaFilter && yourDataObject.getCena().equals("100")) dataobject must be a dataSnapsot. ?